# firebase rules give privilege to firebase user ids stored in a map

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wanted to give delete privs to users ids stored in the moderdores document:
[image]

the followong rules enable the users to delete their own data but not other users data:

```
 service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /Registros/{registroId} {
  allow read; 
  allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userid //||request.auth.uid == resource.data.userid;
  allow create, update: if request.auth.uid != null;

}

}
}
```

I wanted to add an OR for the users stored in the document above.

How can this be done?

I have the user IDs of the moderators in a value stored. How can this map accessed in the rules?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone with the same problem:

found a solution:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /Registros/{registroId} {
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    function getUser() {
      return request.auth.uid;
    }
    function isOneOfModerator(array) {
      return isSignedIn() && (getUser() in array.data.users);
    }


  allow read; 
  allow delete: if isOneOfModerator(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Admins/moderador))
  allow create, update: if isSignedIn();

}
}
}
```